# Fetch data from two different Tables in one parameter in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I have one parameter `@TAG`, derive data from two different columns. If `Tag_ID` from Table A doesn't exist, then use `Tag_NUMBER` from table B. Instead of creating two separate stored procedures, how do I make `Tag_Number` optional if `Tag_ID` exist and vice versa?

Comment: Please show what you have now along with sample data and expected results

Answer (score 0):

Assuming simple structures, here's an outline of a fairly simple way to do this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
    @Tag    int
AS

    SELECT *
     from FirstTable
     where Tag_ID = @Tag

    IF @@rowcount = 0
        SELECT *
         from SecondTable
         where Tag_Number = @Tag

RETURN
```

And, yes, sample data and examples of preferred output may show this to not be effective.

Comment: its not letting me post my sample but I want a scenario where if the user passes in a Tag_Id in Tag parameter, it can work or the user passes a tag_number in tag parameter, it still works. so TagID is from another table and TagNumber is from another table.

Comment: Are you receiving two parameters, or one parameter that might have one of two values? Are the two tables joined somehow, or would they require separate queries, like in my (first) example?

Comment: one parameter might have one of two values and the two tables are joined

Comment: For this, we'd really need to see the structures of the two tables, along with how they are to be joined.